# Web API that contacts to Xero in C#

Tags: c#, xero-api

I want to make web api which contacts to XERO.

Can anyone please help how to create rest api for this.

I have tried following but it is not working
https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Net but it doesnot work without taking user to browser.

I have also tried to create Following

```
var private_app_api = new XeroCoreApi("https://api.xero.com", new 
                  PrivateAuthenticator(@"C:\Dev\your_public_privatekey.pfx"),
                  new Consumer("your-consumer-key", "your-consumer-secret"), 
                  null,
                  new DefaultMapper(), new DefaultMapper());
```

but from Xero.Api.Core i am getting

```
"Error CS1729 'XeroCoreApi' does not contain a constructor that takes 6 arguments AHFXEROService"
```

Can anybody please help??

Comment: Intellisense should show how many exact arguments required for the constructor and what are the types if them.

Comment: https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Net/blob/c7da77cdf22d0bc525eb6a8454196d726fe79a7d/Xero.Api/Core/XeroCoreApi.cs

Comment: from some reference i got to know that i need exact this parameters for creating xero api but in "Xero.api.core" library there's no method which has exactly these parameters. so i think there has to be some another library

Comment: Now i am struggling with oauth2. as i have windows app from which i need to make user login. i can redirect them to login but they need call back uri i dont know how to make xero redirect to my windows app. Any idea ?